# Python: Numpy tile in the 3rd dimension

Tags: python, numpy, tile

I would like to tile my array in 3 dimension in order to obtain the following result:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])

i = 3
j = 2
k = 2

...after tiling...

out = [[[1,1,1]
        [1,1,1]]

       [[2,2,2]
        [2,2,2]]]
```

I would like to use np.tile some how (here I'm showing an example with a simple 2D array but I have to deal with a much longer one and cicling with 'for' would be too slow) but even combining a reshape() I cannot obtain the result I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.tile(a.reshape(2,1,1), (1,2,3))
```